# dompdf left div on every page, but without it's elements except first page

Tags: html, laravel, dompdf

[image]

---

I am using laravel dompdf to create resumes. I have colored left div and right div without color. I want left div to be shown on every page. But I want it's elements to be shown only on first page. How can I do it ?

Comment: So, I want elements of left div to be shown only on first page

Comment: how to show content in left div in all pages

Comment: how to get left div in all pages

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to use fixed positioning for your two sidebars and separately position your content absolutely. Up through and including dompdf 0.7.0, fixed-position content will duplicate across pages while absolutely-positioned content currently renders only on the current page.

```css
@page { margin: 50px 120px; }
.left-col { position: fixed; left: -1100px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 80px; background-color: green; }
.left-col.content { position: absolute; padding: 5px; font-size: .85em; }
.right-col { position: fixed; right: -1100px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; width: 80px; background-color: brown; }
```

```html
<div class="left-col"></div>
  <div class="left-col content">
    <!-- first-page column content -->
  </div>
  <div class="right-col"></div>

  <div>
    <!-- main document content -->
  </div>
```

Comment: I think there must be another better way. if I can get variable for page number I can solve it.

Comment: or may be I can use gradient ?

Comment: I did as you said. It helped, but the text does not go to the next page. It somehow overflows

Comment: I think that problem with absolute positioning. And for laravel there is not 0.7 version of dompdf

Comment: Not sure what kind of problem you're having. This should work with dompdf 0.6.0. Absolutely-positioned content will not page in these versions. So make sure you put your main content in the div that has the "main document content" comment.

Comment: Unless you want all of the left column to show on the first page regardless of the amount of content. That's a bit more difficult. Can you post an image showing exactly what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: I have done it, but now the rest of the text on the right is not shown on the second page.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the HTML you are using?

Comment: I solved this problem, thanks. I had given position relative to main content div. I deleted positioning style and it worked :)